# MVC - how to send to the partial view ViewModel containing a list

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, model, asp.net-mvc-partialview

I am the beginner in MVC and I have a web application, where in my controller I declare a list of objects (feedback from visitors) and then send it to the view, which displays it. It looks like this. Declaration:

```
public class TrekFeedbackItem
    {   
        public string trekid { get; set; }
        public string comment { get; set; }
        public string author { get; set; }

        public TrekFeedbackItem(string trekid, string comment, string author)
        {   this.trekid = trekid;
            this.comment = comment;
            this.author = author;
        }    
    }
```

And usage:

```
List<TrekFeedbackItem> feedbackList = new List<TrekFeedbackItem>
{
  //constructor called, data entered into the list 
}
return View(trekname, feedbackList);
```

However, now I need to pass also another list, lets call it *relatedblogsList*. As a first step, I decided to encapsulate my feedbackList into the ViewModel (and once it works, add another list of different objects.)

```
public class TrekViewModel
    {
        public List<TrekFeedbackItem> feedback { get; set; }
    }
```

and fill the data like this:

```
TrekViewModel trek = new TrekViewModel();
trek.feedback = new List<TrekFeedbackItem>
    {
    //insert data here     
    };
return View(view, trek);
```

The problem is - **how to send this model to the partial view and how to access it**?

Thank a lot

Comment: In the View, you are inserting an object of the TrekViewModel class rather than the list itself. "trek" isn't a list.

Comment: you need to set model of your partial view to ``TrekViewModel``

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass data into the partial view like below

from the controller return this view:

```
return PartialView("_partial_viewname", trek);
```

then in the beginning of the partial view:

```
@model Models.TrekViewModel
```

after that you can use `Model.feedback` inside the partial view.

Comment: Hi, if I use `return PartialView("_partial_viewname, trek);` in my Master layout, I get the error **The name trek does not exist in the current context**. Any idea how to fix it?

Comment: Hi, return PartialView("_partialViewName, viewModel); should be in the controller action method and partial view should have the @model modelPath.TrekViewModel, if those two steps are correct then model object in the same context (in you case it is trek view model).

Comment: Hi, now I can see (after I put the break point into partial view) that Model was sent correctly. The last problem - I want to iterate through this model and display the data. How to do it? I use this command - `foreach (var std in Model.feedback as IList<MVC.Controllers.TrekViewModel)`. But I am not able to access individual properties by this command - `@std.feedback.comment` Any ideas how to do it?

Comment: Hi, you are iterating through the Model.feedback list items, once you add code like foreach (var std in Model.feedback) no need to go inside feedback list again, because items are assign to the std variable in each loop. so just use the  @std.comment

Comment: I also though so, but when I use @std.comment, Visual Studio shows me error "MVC.Controllers.TrekViewModel does not contain a definition for 'comment' and no extension method 'comment' accepting a first argument of type MVC.Controllers.TrekViewModel"

Comment: OK, it seems the problem is here - `foreach (var std in Model.feedback as IList<MVC.Controllers.TrekViewModel>)`. I get NullReferenceException when I get here - seems the data wasnt loaded. I used this to declare the model `@model MVC.Controllers.TreViewModel`

Comment: Done. I had to use this :) - `foreach (var std in Model.feedback)`

Answer (score 1):

Set return type of your action controller to "**PartialView**" rather than "**View**".

```
return PartialView("_yourPartialViewName", yourObject);
```

In case, if application does not work as expected, build it and re-run it.

Comment: Hi, I am using this command in the master layout -  `@Html.Partial("~/Views/Shared/Sub/sidebar_trek.cshtml")`. After some more googling, I found out that I dont need to pass that "trek" to the partial view once more, it can be accessed by partial view if I send it to the master layout.
What I dont now now is - how to access this model in the partial view?

Comment: Make sure your master view is strongly typed with your view model otherwise it would not work. On the top of your master layout add `@model Models.TrekViewModel`. Now you can access this model in the body of view like this: `@Model.feedback`.

Comment: Thank you. When I put breakpoint into my partial view, I can see my Model with data - they were sent correctly. The last problem - I want to iterate through this model and display the data. How to do it? I use this command - `foreach (var std in Model.feedback as IList<MVC.Controllers.TrekViewModel)`. But I am not able to access individual properties by this command - `@std.feedback.comment` Any ideas how to do it?

Comment: Try `@std.comment`.

Comment: Tried before, also doesnt work. When I open partial view in debug mode, I see following structure: this -> Base -> Model -> feedback -> [0]/[1] (model has 2 entries right now) -> properties author/comment/trekid (with correct values). Now only to find out how to display them :)